# etc/paths modifications not taken into account in OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, path, osx-mountain-lion

I installed node.js, pip, rvm a few weeks ago. I just installed them and checked everything was working fine.

Yesterday, as I tried to install howdoi (https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi) using zsh via pip, I got a pip : command not found error message.

The echo $PATH command gave me this:

```
"rvm stuffs":/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
```

Then, I checked the etc/paths file:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

It looks like /usr/local/bin is in my etc/paths file but not in my path.

I temporarily fixed this with a temporary solution:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/etc/paths
```

This morning, I am looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this to your ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, or ~/.bash_profile. In Terminal:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.profile
PATH=/usr/local/bin:\$PATH; export PATH
EOF
```

Open a new Terminal (Command + N) and test the change:

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: It looks like it is has added /usr/local/bin in my path after my "rvm stuffs". So it is working. Thanks you. I would really like to know why I have to do this as the first line of my /etc/paths file is /usr/local/bin. Weird, isn'it? Why do I have to add per shell settings when I already add system-wide settings (PS: Shell newbie :-)).

Comment: @politicus - since zsh is a different shell than bash it's possible upon installation the path was put in .zsh_profile, but not in .bash_profile — so now that you've got it referenced in bash shell you should be good.